# Angular Material adding the primary color to a Div

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using [Angular Material 2](https://material.angular.io/) and I am trying to add the primary color to a div.

This is what I've done:

```
<div class="myDiv background-primary-color white-text">This is a Div</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that It's adding no color to it.

Comment: Adding the classnames won't do anything. You need to add corresponding css to apply those styles.

Comment: I tried color="primary" but it did nothing

Comment: Angular Material doesn't provide generic classes for behavior like that. Check out https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to use `color` attribute on non-material elements (and not all Angular Material elements support it). But you can follow a little hacky way: import a palette and store the color to the variable in SASS/LESS, so when you will change the current palette - this color will be changed too. Here is an awesome explanation step by step: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46760925/6053654

Comment: Oh cool, casually browsing and seeing a work around I posted being reposted for others :D Hope It helps OP