# Ho to use angular theme for all Markup elements?

Tags: css, sass, angular-material

Is it possible to use Angular Material theme for text and other HTML elements such text, header, links etc. ?

I would like to use something like following:

```
<h2 color="'primary'">Text to be colored</h2>
```

I have been searching and found this posting e.g. [Get Material 2 theme color scheme/palette for other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760306/get-material-2-theme-color-scheme-palette-for-other-elements), but it seems to be too much and I also won't agree to use just `scss` files instead of `css`.

Is there an simpler way to achieve this? For instance adding extra definition for the other elements in `theme.scss`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class to set the colour in your styles:

```html
<h2 class="app-primary">Primary</h2>
```

This method assumes that you have a custom theme:

```scss
$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
// ...

.app-primary {
    color: mat-color($app-primary);
}
```

Or:

```css
.app-primary {
    /* Insert hard-coded value here */
    color: #3F51B5;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do have a custom theme: `@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-pink, 700, 900);
$app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-light-green, 600, 900, A100);
$app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-grey);
$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);`

Comment: First Option with theme working like a charm! Fixed.