# get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using angular-cli at the command line, I executed:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt styl
```

to set the default styling to Stylus and I got this response:

> get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command

I want to change the style extension on an EXISTING project to use SCSS. How do I do this using the config command? Where is the documentation for ng config?

I am using Angular CLI v6.0.0

ng help says:

> config Get/set configuration values

but doesn't elaborate. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/config

Comment: very useful link thanks - but not sure which value in the config needs altering to achieve this

Comment: why wouldn't you just replace `set` with `config`?  why would the key/value be different?

Comment: There seems to be a change in the layout of the config file in angular-cli v6

Comment: [https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors)

Comment: please add your comment as answer and I will accept this since it is from official docs thx

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For Angular 6 you want to use the following command:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext styl
```

This will automatically add the "schematics" section halfer mentioned to the angular.json file.

Here is the official documentation:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors

Comment: I replaced `styl` with `scss` , that is `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss`

Comment: Yes, this would be the correct way to change the default style extension to that of a sass file. I had put `styl` in my response because the individual asking the question was asking about changing the default styling to that of Stylus. That argument can be changed to whatever file extension you would like the default to be.

Comment: I missed that. Didn't know the person was talking about stylus. Your answer is of course right.

Comment: To setup for sass use the following: ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss -g

Answer (score 24):

OK I did a diff on a project generated with:

```
ng new --style=styl PROJECT_NAME
```

and the same without the --style flag and the differences in the angular.json config file are represented in the 2 .png files attached.

Using these diffs, I manually made the changes to **angular.json** as follows:

(1) Change `projects.PROJECT_NAME.schematics` as follows:

```
"schematics": {                                                                                    
  "@schematics/angular:component": {                                                               
    "styleext": "styl"                                                                             
  }                                                                                                
}
```

(2) Change `projects.PROJECT_NAME.architect.build.options.styles` as follows:

```
"styles": [                                                                                  
    "src/styles.styl"                                                                          
]
```

(3) Change `projects.PROJECT_NAME.architect.test.options.styles` as follows:

```
"styles": [                                                                                  
  "styles.styl"                                                                              
]
```

(4) Rename src/styles.css to src/styles.styl

Your existing components will happily continue to use `.css` but new components will now be generated with `.styl` files.

Diffs in PNG format as follows:

[image]

...

[image]

Comment: Where did you find this solution? Thanks, i'll try it for scss. These changes.

Comment: I didn't find this solution - I worked it out by doing a git diff on a project generated using the --style flag and a project generated without using that flag - glad it worked for u too :)

Comment: clever dude ;-)

Answer (score 7):

`ng config projects.PROJECT_NAME.schematics.@schematics/angular:component '{ styleext: "scss"}'`

for a specific project or for the default across all projects

`ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component '{ styleext: "scss"}'`

Comment: the second one is not working with me. I received: "Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: Oh, in order to use it we need to add a -g in the end: 
`ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component '{ styleext: "scss"}' -g`

Comment: but even that being added to angular-config, ng new is still creating the project as css  :(

Comment: even with `-g` I get `Invalid JSON character: "s" at 0:11.`

Comment: I found a slightly different version of this which worked great and comes straight from the Angular-cli documentation.
[https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors)