# Using current Angular material theme colors in other css

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, themes

I am using custom themes in my app, which depending on the environment either uses dark or light theme (themes.css):

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$myapp-light-theme-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, 700, 300, 900);
$myapp-light-theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette);
$myapp-light-theme-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$deep-orange-palette, A200);

// create theme (use mat-dark-theme for themes with dark backgrounds)
$myapp-light-theme: mat.define-light-theme((color: (primary: $myapp-light-theme-primary,
                accent: $myapp-light-theme-accent,
                warn: $myapp-light-theme-warn),
            typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
            density: 0,
        ));

$myapp-dark-theme-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$light-blue-palette, A200);
$myapp-dark-theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$light-green-palette, A200);
$myapp-dark-theme-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$yellow-palette, A200);

$myapp-dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme((color: (primary: $myapp-dark-theme-primary,
                accent: $myapp-dark-theme-accent,
                warn: $myapp-dark-theme-warn),
            typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
            density: 0,
        ));


// Apply the dark theme by default
@include mat.core-theme($myapp-light-theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($myapp-light-theme);


// Apply the light theme only when the user prefers light themes.
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    // Use the `-color` mixins to only apply color styles without reapplying the same
    // typography and density styles.
    @include mat.core-theme($myapp-dark-theme);
    @include mat.all-component-themes($myapp-dark-theme);
}
```

Now I want to style my snackbar notifications with these colors. This should work via the `panelClass` property of `MatSnackBarConfig` passed onto the alert. This basically, adds another class to the snackbar. Example I found suggested to add these definitions to the `styles.css`:

```
.custom-snackbar {
    .mat-mdc-snack-bar-container .mdc-snackbar__surface {
        border-radius: 8px !important;
    }

    .mat-mdc-button.mat-mdc-snack-bar-action {
        color: white !important;
    }
}

.snackbar-success {
    .mdc-snackbar__surface {
        background-color: green !important;
    }

    .mdc-snackbar__label {
        color: white !important;
    }
}

.snackbar-error {
    .mdc-snackbar__surface {
        background-color: red !important;
    }

    .mdc-snackbar__label {
        color: white !important;
    }
}

.snackbar-info {
    .mdc-snackbar__surface {
        background-color: var(--color-accent) !important;
    }

    .mdc-snackbar__label {
        color: white !important;
    }
}

.snackbar-warn {
    .mdc-snackbar__surface {
        background-color: yellow !important;
    }

    .mdc-snackbar__label {
        color: black !important;
    }

    .mat-mdc-button.mat-mdc-snack-bar-action {
        color: black !important;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how I can access the current primary/accent/warn colors of my theme? I can't use specifically dark or light theme colors, as some users will use one or the other. I was thinking that there must be a purely CSS way to get the current primary/accent/warn colors and use them to style the panel classes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set those colors into variables and use them in other CSS files. Here is an example inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54259083/2900822). That answer did not work for me directly but the following did in the past:

```
// Apply the dark theme by default
@include mat.core-theme($myapp-light-theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($myapp-light-theme);

:root {
    --color-primary: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($myapp-light-theme-primary, default)};
    --color-accent: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($myapp-light-theme-accent, default)};
    --color-warn: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($myapp-light-theme-warn, default)};
}

// Apply the light theme only when the user prefers light themes.
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    // Use the `-color` mixins to only apply color styles without reapplying the same
    // typography and density styles.
    @include mat.core-theme($myapp-dark-theme);
    @include mat.all-component-themes($myapp-dark-theme);

    :root {
        --color-primary: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($myapp-dark-theme-primary, default)};
        --color-accent: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($myapp-dark-theme-accent, default)};
        --color-warn: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($myapp-dark-theme-warn, default)};
    }
}
```

I don't know if the function name changed in between but I had to dig into `@use '@angular/material' as mat;`, where I noticed `get-color-from-palette`. On another [site](https://fireflysemantics.medium.com/using-angular-get-color-from-palette-to-retrieve-color-values-bcd0a78a590) I found that there is a default key (=500).

Now to use the colors, you only have to use the `var` function:

```
background-color: var(--color-primary);
```