# Angular Material Theming, changing colors programatically

Tags: angular, sass, material-design, theming

I'm using custom theming as per the instructions [HERE](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) and it works great! Except I want my users to have the ability to choose their own colors. I can't seem to figure out how to programmatically change theme colors in my components.

Specifically, I want to get the colors for my users from a database, and then apply them to the app when they sign into their account.

Comment: Well that sucks!

Comment: That's not entirely true. Follow the instructions in the answer here, I had it done in 10 min! https://stackoverflow.com/a/42790288/6841518