# How to export custom colors and use them in components?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a defined Sass variable in one of my components but it seems that this color is either not exported globally or this is not how this is done at all.

In my **style.scss** file I am declaring a color `$foo`

```js
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$foo: mat-color($mat-blue, 50);
```

I am trying to apply this color in one of my components (as I would with `primary`, `accent` or `warn`:

```xml
<button mat-fab color="foo">
  OK
</button>
```

However, this does not work and I would like to know/understand why this is the case.

I've been reading [the docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components) and [some tutorials](https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/how-to-use-angular-material-2-sass-variables-in-your-components-76ce0203f126) also [this guideline](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming-your-components.md) but I can't seem to find anything with a little more detail to this..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot specify another color attribute apart from those defined by Angular. I am no expert on this but what I do is creating class and use that:

```
$foo: mat-color($mat-blue, 50);

.mat-foo {
  color: $foo !important;
}
```

And then....

```
<button mat-fab class="mat-foo">OK</button>
```

Another approach could be creating [attribute directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives). That way, if you change your class or anything, you can change that in one place only.

```
import {Directive, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[yourappFoo]'
})
export class FooDirective {

  @HostBinding('class.mat-foo') c = true;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

...and:

```
<button mat-fab yourappFoo>OK</button>
```